# How to set/get form id in ninja form?

Tags: templates, identity, ninja-forms

I am going to export pdf using ninja form.
I have many forms and I want to expert different template pdf for every forms.
For this, I have to identify which form is submitted in pdf.php.

```
for example)
// pdf.php

   if ($form_id = 'user_portfolio'){
      echo 'username :'.$field[1][value];
   }
   if ($form_id = 'user_friend'){
      echo 'userfriend :'.$field[1][value];
   }
```

Now I don't know how to set form id when build ninja form.
And how to get form id.
how to set/get form id?

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to figure this out myself for a while, but I finally have it!

First, the variable is `$form_ID` (with the ID in caps.)

That variable is set elsewhere in the plugin, so you have to match the case.

You grab the ID number from the main Ninja Forms screen (the number listed under short code).

[image]

What's great is you can make a seperate php file for each form template and include that in you pdf.php template.

Just swap out the numbers in the code below for your form numbers.

Modify if and elseif, etc.,  as needed.

```
    <?php if ($form_ID=="4"): ?>

        <?php include 'LVP-pdf'; ?>

    <?php elseif ($form_ID=="7"): ?>

         Other Code Here

    <?php endif; ?>
```